# Referencing jQuery in Google Telephone tracking callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api

I'm implementing Google Telephone tracking which has 2 elements:

1) Tracking script in the

```js
//Google Telephone Number Tracking
(function(a,e,c,f,g,b,d){var h={ak:"XXXXXX",cl:"XXXXXXX"};a[c]=a[c]||function(){(a[c].q=a[c].q||[]).push(arguments)};a[f]||(a[f]=h.ak);b=e.createElement(g);b.async=1;b.src="//www.gstatic.com/wcm/loader.js";d=e.getElementsByTagName(g)[0];d.parentNode.insertBefore(b,d);a._googWcmGet=function(b,d,e){a[c](2,b,h,d,null,new Date,e)}})(window,document,"_googWcmImpl","_googWcmAk","script");
```

and the call which I have in the footer of the page:

```js
var callback = function(formatted_number, unformatted_number ) {
  console.log(1);
   jQuery("a.tel").each(function(index, element) {
    element.html('');
    element.prop('href', 'tel:' + unformatted_number);
    element.text(formatted_number);
   });
  };
  
  jQuery(document).ready(function () {
   console.log('before google');
   _googWcmGet(callback, '020 8953 5566');
   console.log('after google');
  });
```

The problem I have is that the jQuery object in the callback is giving me a `TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the callback function. I need to target a class and already have jQuery loaded but can't figure out what I'm missing. Do I need to pass a jQuery object in the function?

Full page is at http://www.scienceboffins.co.uk/

Comment: What should be added to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/wsj6r7co/) to reproduce error?

Comment: Sorry, I was just trying to embed the code. It wasn't intended to be run. If you visit the site, you can see the error in the console.log

Comment: I visited site - there are no related errors in console (only _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined_ in impl-1_13.js:41)

Comment: My apologies. It requires a click thru from a google adword. IF you Google 'science party' and then click on the www.scienceboffins.co.uk link you should see it.

Comment: Well, still no luck (no errors). I actually still see both _before google_ and _after google_ in console.